# bitbucket-pipeline and anchors - Steps are not executed

Tags: bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

I have the following yaml file

```
# Define anchors for reuse
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &setup_staging
        name: Setup staging deployment
        script:
          - echo "HelLo 1"

    - step: &terraform_plan
        name: Execute terraform init and plan
        script:
          - echo "HelLo 2"
    
infrastructure_plan_staging: &infrastructure_plan_staging
 - step: *setup_staging
 - step: *terraform_plan
 
pipelines:
  default:
    - <<: *infrastructure_plan_staging
```

Only the `setup_staging` step is executed, and I'm not sure why. I have also tried

```
infrastructure_plan_staging: &infrastructure_plan_staging
 <<: *setup_staging
 <<: *terraform_plan
```

Which layouts the same result.
I think the issue is with my anchors definition, but I cannot find the exact reasons.

What I want to achieve is 1) Export dev variable in step_1 and 2) Use these variable in step_2.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure how the YAML merge operator is working there, and can't test it now, but I'd go for.

```yaml
# Define anchors for reuse
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:
    - &setup_staging_step
        name: Setup staging deployment
        script:
          - echo "HelLo 1"

    - &terraform_plan_step
        name: Execute terraform init and plan
        script:
          - echo "HelLo 2"

    - &infrastructure_plan_staging_pipeline
      - step: *setup_staging_step
      - step: *terraform_plan_step

pipelines:
  default: *infrastructure_plan_staging_pipeline
```

Note Bitbucket Pipelines --the *application*-- does not care about where you put anchor definitions nor their key, but might be concerned about a top-level "`infrastructure_plan_staging`" key outside the definitions block.

Also note, when in doubt, you can locally inspect the resulting pipeline loading the file with your favorite tool, e.g. in python:

```py
import yaml

pipeline = yaml.safe_load(open("bitbucket-pipelines.yml"))
print(pipeline["pipelines"]["default"])
```